# Accessing session value in django template

Tags: django, session, django-templates

I am setting

```
request.session['total_items'] = 3
```

in a views.py file of a django app

in template
 i got to know that you can access it as `{{request.session.total_items}}`

Everything is fine and i'm able to get the value.

However,my question is that why it is not `{{request.session['total_items']}}` instead, since request.session is a dictionary like object.

For `{{request.session['total_items']}}`, its giving an error as following:

```
Could not parse the remainder: '['total_items']' from 'request.session['total_items']'
```

Any help would be appreciated ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not confuse Django template language with Python Syntax. Django template language its a language on its own and have its own way of performing things. As [doc](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter04.html) suggests:

> The goal is not to invent a programming language. The goal is to offer
>   just enough programming-esque functionality, such as branching and
>   looping, that is essential for making presentation-related decisions.

Comment: I wonder Why negative vote? One can not argue that if particular code works in Python then it should behave exactly as in Django Template? The question logic is why it behaves differently the OP surely knows that dot notation works.

Comment: Thanks Aamir for your comment :)

Answer (score 1):

When you have enabled the [django.core.context_processors.request](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request) it will enable the access to the values of a dictionary-like objects with the `.` notation.
This will convert any Python object into something that the Django template language will understand as it is its own language.

This also applies for the following:

1. Attribute lookups (eg. myobject.age)
2. Method calls (eg. myobject.age())
3. List indices (eg mylist.1)

The thing that is working it behind the scenes is the [`Context` object.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/api/#django.template.Context)
You can read more on how it works [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) and [here](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter04.html)

And you can compare the Python controlstructure `if` to Django's template language.

```
if object:
    myobject.dostuff()
```

to

```
{% if object %}
    {{ myobject.dostuff }}
{% endif %}
```

If you want a **closer** match to Python you should check out

- [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/)
- [PyHAML](https://github.com/mikeboers/PyHAML)